# Question about extending "locally" local sections

Tags: differential-topology

I wonder if the following is true:

> Let $\pi : E \rightarrow M$ be a vector bundle over a smooth manifold
> $M$, $U$ an open set of $M$, and $r \in \Gamma(U,E)$ a local smooth
> section defined on $U$. Then, for every point $p \in U$, there exists
> a neighborhood $V$ of $p$ in $M$, whose closure is completely
> contained in $U$, and a global section $s \in \Gamma(E)$ which
> coincides with $r$ in $V$.

My idea is to reduce the support of $r$ to a compact set, and then use the pasting lemma for open subsets to extend trivially (by $0$) to a global section, but I couldn't concrete an argument.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: As always, think bump function and/or partition of unity.